# Create a Pandas Column based on n-th repetition of a value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
userId  dateTime

2233    2018-08-01 12:30:29
1455    2018-08-01 13:08:01
2233    2018-08-01 15:08:01
1909    2018-08-01 15:18:01
2233    2018-08-01 17:58:01
1455    2018-08-01 19:08:01
```

So I want to append a new column, based on the nth time the same user is appearing. So my desired dataframe will look something like this:

```
userId  dateTime             Appearance_no

2233    2018-08-01 12:30:29    1
1455    2018-08-01 13:08:01    1
2233    2018-08-01 15:08:01    2
1909    2018-08-01 15:18:01    1
2233    2018-08-01 17:58:01    3
1455    2018-08-01 19:08:01    2
```

which is almost similar like a serial no., but I'm not able to generate the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cumcount

```
df['Appearance_no'] = df.groupby('userId')['userId'].cumcount() + 1

    userId  dateTime              Appearance_no
0   2233    2018-08-01 12:30:29   1
1   1455    2018-08-01 13:08:01   1
2   2233    2018-08-01 15:08:01   2
3   1909    2018-08-01 15:18:01   1
4   2233    2018-08-01 17:58:01   3
5   1455    2018-08-01 19:08:01   2
```

Comment: hi, works fine. wanted to know if you can help me out with one small thing. I want to merge two dataframes based on datetime column, but for example i want the datetime of the other dataframe to be within a certain limit. For ex. lets consider this as first dataframe and userId 2233, time is 12:30, so i want to join with other dataframe where date is same and time lies within the range of 12:30-1:30, is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is. It would be better if you post another question with sample dataframe for the same.

Comment: i get an error `Wrong number of items passed 6, placement implies 1`, for the answer that you posted, it was taking some time, so i thought will work out, but didn't

Comment: @Vaishali ... be sure to edit the text as you do not use `rank` here.

Comment: @Vaishali I created a separate question for that datetime thing I asked. You can view it here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52215318/merging-two-dataframes-in-pandas-based-on-time-range