# Merging two Dataframes in Pandas based on time-range difference

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have these two dataframes, `df1`,`df2`.

df1:

```
dateTime                 userId  session

2018-08-30 02:20:19      2233      1
2018-08-30 05:32:10      1933      1
2018-08-30 09:10:39      2233      2
2018-08-30 10:26:59      2233      3
2018-08-30 11:56:25      4459      1
2018-08-30 12:30:55      4459      1
```

df2:

```
clickTime                 userId  session  clickId

2018-08-30 02:21:09      2233               1987
2018-08-30 02:23:19      2233               1988
2018-08-30 02:24:00      2233               1989
2018-08-30 02:32:09      2233               1990
2018-08-30 05:33:10      1933               2009
2018-08-30 05:35:19      1933               2010
2018-08-30 05:36:59      1933               2011
2018-08-30 11:57:25      4459               3012
2018-08-30 11:58:55      4459               3013
```

I want to merge the two dataframes on `userId` and also the time-range columns, which falls within say a range of 10 mins. of `df1`.

So my dataframe that I want is something like this:

```
  dateTime               userId  session   clickTime             clickId

2018-08-30 02:20:19      2233      1       2018-08-30 02:21:09    1987
2018-08-30 02:20:19      2233      1       2018-08-30 02:23:19    1988
2018-08-30 02:20:19      2233      1       2018-08-30 02:21:09    1989
2018-08-30 02:20:19      2233      1       2018-08-30 02:21:09    1990
```

So  I want them for each user, dataframe should look like this, for each `userId` I want this  dataframe. Is it possible?

So its like I want to merge `df1` and `df2` on `userId` as well as `clickTime` of `df2` should lie with a time range of say 10-15mins of `dateTime` column of `df1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC: Use [**`pandas.merge_asof`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html)

```
pd.merge_asof(
    df1, df2,
    left_on='dateTime',
    right_on='clickTime',
    by='userId',
    direction='nearest'
)

             dateTime  userId  session           clickTime  clickId
0 2018-08-30 02:20:19    2233        1 2018-08-30 02:21:09     1987
1 2018-08-30 05:32:10    1933        1 2018-08-30 05:33:10     2009
2 2018-08-30 09:10:39    2233        2 2018-08-30 02:32:09     1990
3 2018-08-30 10:26:59    2233        3 2018-08-30 02:32:09     1990
4 2018-08-30 11:56:25    4459        1 2018-08-30 11:57:25     3012
5 2018-08-30 12:30:55    4459        1 2018-08-30 11:58:55     3013
```

---

You can specify a tolerance on how far away to look

```
pd.merge_asof(
    df1, df2,
    left_on='dateTime',
    right_on='clickTime',
    by='userId',
    direction='nearest',
    tolerance=pd.Timedelta(15, unit='m')
)

             dateTime  userId  session           clickTime  clickId
0 2018-08-30 02:20:19    2233        1 2018-08-30 02:21:09   1987.0
1 2018-08-30 05:32:10    1933        1 2018-08-30 05:33:10   2009.0
2 2018-08-30 09:10:39    2233        2                 NaT      NaN
3 2018-08-30 10:26:59    2233        3                 NaT      NaN
4 2018-08-30 11:56:25    4459        1 2018-08-30 11:57:25   3012.0
5 2018-08-30 12:30:55    4459        1                 NaT      NaN
```

Comment: Is there a way to fix the `NaT` values, because I want it to match the two columns, `clickTime` is basically dependant on `dateTime` because without `dateTime`, `clickTime` won't be possible.

Comment: It is also not merging repetitive values, only unique `userId` s are joined